# Trying to design an order form that links with Venmo and PayPal

Tags: forms, paypal, venmo

I have a client that wants an order form for service on his website.  He is requesting a form that will add up all the options and then allow online payments through either PayPal or Venmo.  I have searched online and cannot seem to locate the correct template that he can use.  Are there any suggestions or templates that will easily translate to their website.  I am trying to do this as simply as possible.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To process the payment, use PayPal's [Standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) with `&enable-funding=venmo` as a query parameter to the SDK.

You can find a demo with sample code at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Adding up all the options and calculating a total will need to be done with Javascript -- or on the server side before order creation if you implement a server-based integration.

Comment: I will look into that, the javascript should be easy to locate.  Thank you